# Look forward very much to

Tags: grammar, phrases, verbs, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

One example of Cambridge grammar confuses me.

> I look forward very much to hearing from you soon.

Is the sentence correct? Why does it put "very much" together with verb phrase "look forward to", instead between subject and verb, or at the end of sentence? Doesn’t this remove the infinitive of the verb?

This reminds me of the Italian word "trattarsi di"，if an adverb is added, it is usually placed after the verb.

Comment: I can't explain exactly why, but I prefer "I very much look forward to hearing from you soon". There is some advice at [grammar.com](https://www.grammar.com/2-where-do-adverbs-go) about adverb placement.

Comment: @WeatherVane and Killing time,I did some searching and these might be the answers to my question.https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/32800/infinitives-to-split-or-not https://law.marquette.edu/facultyblog/2014/02/to-split-or-not-to-split-that-is-the-question/ thanks anyway

Comment: Putting it at the end would separate it too much from the verb it modifies. "I look forward to hearing from you soon very much" sounds awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To* is a preposition—not an infinitive marker—in the “phrasal-prepositional verb” *look forward to*.<sup>*</sup>

[According to *Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/phrasal-verbs-and-multi-word-verbs):

> Phrasal-prepositional verbs have three parts: a verb, a particle, and
> a preposition. The particle and the preposition cannot be separated.

Neither can the verb and its particle be separated by an adverbial. So keep it together:

> *I very much **look forward to** hearing from you soon.*

<sub>*Grammar terms vary.</sub>

Comment: The rule states that phrasal-prepositional verbs should not be separated, but examples provided include phrases like "to boldly go..." from Star Trek and "my first serve hit a plane causing it to go tragically off..." from Family Guy. Are these instances considered special exceptions, or are they informal usage?

Answer (score 2):

> > I look forward very much to hearing from you soon.
>
> Is the sentence correct? Why does it put "very much" together with verb phrase "look forward to", instead between subject and verb, or at the end of sentence?

The sentence is correct as-is, but I agree that it's more natural to put "very much" between the subject and the verb.

Using Google Ngram Viewer to compare "look forward very much to" to "very much look forward to" over time, it seems that:

- [In American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+forward+very+much+to%2Cvery+much+look+forward+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3), "look forward very much to" used to be somewhat more common, but was overtaken by "very much look forward to" more than 40 years ago, and today the latter is more than four times as common.
- [In British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+forward+very+much+to%2Cvery+much+look+forward+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3), the situation is similar, but less extreme: "very much look forward to" overtook "look forward very much to" only about 30 years ago, and even today it's barely three times as common.

So there may not be a general reason to expect one version to be more common; maybe, when an expression suddenly becomes more popular (as this one did), it can be a bit random which version ends up being the most common?

> Doesn’t this remove the infinitive of the verb?

I'm not sure what you mean by this. It's true that there's no infinitive in your example, but that would also be the case without "very much". ("I look forward to hearing from you soon.") I wonder if you've misunderstood the term *[infinitive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infinitive)*?

Comment: Perhaps OP misinterprets the preposition in *I look forward **to** hearing from you* as an infinitive marker (which it would be, in *I hope **to** hear from you*).